# Find if DateTime is within period, with optional boundaries?

Tags: java, c#

I made the following code to find if the current date is within a specific period, but with optional boundaries:

```
func isElligiblePeriod() {
    now = new Date();

    if (!validFrom && !validTo) {
        return true;
    } elseif (now >= validFrom && now <= validTo) {
        return true;
    } elseif (!validTo && now >= validFrom) {
        return true;
    } elseif (!validFrom && now <= validTo) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Basically, this means that the check will happen if there is a validTo date, a validFrom, both or none. The date is always valid if there are no constraints, can be checked agaisnt each one individually. However, this code is ugly as hell. How can i improve this?

Comment: This looks like `javascript` to me, not `java` or `c#`.

Comment: Pseudo-code, actually. I didn't want to clutter the example, since syntax is not the issue.

Comment: If you have working code and want it reviewed then you might want to post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SonerGönül That loosely resembles GO

Comment: @juharr This won't be suited on Code Review, since the O.P. doesn't even know what language this was made. Also, it is missing too much to be even a working code, in whatever language it is.

Comment: Is working code really necessary for recommending a better code structure? I mean... it's a bunch of if's and elif's.

Comment: @vinnylinux: It's helpful as it avoids the fact that it's pseudo-code being a distraction.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this was cross-posted on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100814/improving-date-range-check-with-optional-boundaries (deleted by owner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
// Check the lower bound, if we have one
if (validFrom && now < validFrom)
{
    return false;
}
// Check the upper bound, if we have one
if (validTo && now > validTo)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Or as a conditional:

```
return validFrom && now < validFrom ? false
    : validTo && now > validTo ? false
    : true;
```

Or as a single condition:

```
return !(validFrom && now < validFrom)
    && !(validTo && now > validTo);
```

Or:

```
return (!validFrom || now >= validFrom)
    && (!validTo || now <= validTo);
```

Pick whichever approach you find most readable.

Note that it can be *really* readable if you make sure that `validFrom` and `validTo` are always sensible values - with "start of time" and "end of time" values to mean "no from constraint" or "no to constraint". Then you can just have:

```
return validFrom <= now && now <= validTo;
```

As an aside, you might want to consider making the upper bound exclusive. That's often (but not always) a good idea - it means that you can have abutting time periods really easily (where the `validFrom` of one period is the `validTo` of the previous one).

Comment: This could be all simplified to one return statement.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard It would be ugly as hell, but it can.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Perhaps something like `return !( (validFrom && now < validFrom) || (validTo && now > validTo) );`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard As I said, ugly as hell

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel When turned around and properly formatted as in my answer, I'd say it doesn't look bad at all.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Ident it properly on two lines and it is less ugly then having 3 return encapsulated in two ifs IMHO.

Comment: @Chris You are right about it, but I can't do much in a comment.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Refer for the comment I sent to Chris

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Have added lots of different options now :)

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
bool IsElligiblePeriod( DateTime t, DateTime? from, DateTime? to )
{
    return ( from == null || t >= from.Value ) &&
           ( to == null || t <= to.Value );
}
```

Or if we do it in the style of your pseudo code:

```
return ( !validFrom || now >= validFrom ) &&
       ( !validTo || now <= validTo );
```

Alot shorter and neater than a bunch of if's, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, assuming `validFrom` and `validTo` are nullable DateTimes, I prefer:

```
return (now >= validFrom ?? DateTime.MinValue)
    && (now <= validTo ?? DateTime.MaxValue);
```